# android studio firebase / cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

everytime i compile these two errors shows up. any kind of help will be appreciated.

1. "     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1' "
2. " error: package com.google.android.gms.gcm does not exist "

below are my gradle and manifest files.

**Project Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lrtapp.ardentmap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'

    //Google Play Services
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lrtapp.ardentmap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/erlogo"
        android:label="EaseRoute"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyALC_Pis5w391INiqcvnXO7dipxuMP0-JA" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Contact" />
        <activity android:name=".Videos"></activity>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Thanks in advance to those who will help!!**

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure what your error is but your Firebase dependencies must be the same version. You are using 17.3.1 for firebase-messaging but you firebase-core is 16.0.3.

2) You haven't added GCM dependency in gradle :

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'`

But most importantly, why do you want to implement firebase messaging and GCM in the same app? Google strongly recommends you not to. Moreover GCM is shutting down April 2019.

Comment: its kind of okay because this project is only for my school research that is good for a semester.

Comment: it did remove the gcm error tho, then im getting this other error here. idk why but our advisers gave us this project that are really not related to my degree.

Comment: here's the error though. error: method sendNotification in class FirebaseMessagingService cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String
found: Notification
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length in the 
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification());

Comment: the parameter for sendNotification should be remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

Comment: should it be like this? sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("Notification Received"));

Comment: no.. remoteMessage.getData().get("message"); . The notification is a json. It has a "message" key. Or you can send sendNotification("hello world");

Comment: i typed it and there was an error error: method sendNotification in class FirebaseMessagingService cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: it expects another string. sendNotification("hello","hello world");

Comment: I'm sorry,im just not a programming guy at all. Im just taking up digital arts on an IT school, then one of our panel decided to give us a mobile app as an additional requirement for our thesis.